# Aligning a div to center of page while its position is absolute?

Tags: html, css

How can I `align` a `DIV` to the center of my page while its `position` is `absolute`? If possible **without** using javascript.

Comment: What you tried. Did you googled?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726113/3302747 has js fiddle as well

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** This is an old answer and [the answer currently just below this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42362105/618347) gives a nicer solution which works even if your `div` has dynamic width. Another alternative, using `margin: auto`, can be found [here, on a different, but related, question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998303/618347).

You *can* do this if you know the width of the `DIV` you want to centre.

CSS:

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

You position the top left corner in the centre, and then use negative margins which are half of the width to centre it.

Answer (score 20):

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: this worked very well for dynamic width div, awesome!

Comment: Best responsive answer without using flexbox. Thanks!

Comment: To those confused by transform: it is one of the few (if not the only) CSS property for which % refers to the size of the element being styled, not its parent element.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
position: absolute;
width: 600px;
left: 50%
margin-left: -300px;
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get HTML to automatically center anything that is absolutely positioned. Heck, HTML barely centers anything horizontally using CSS margins :-)

As the name implies absolute positioning  is absolute where you get top and left fixed positions and any margins are applied relative to those positions. Auto is ignored with absolute positioning.

There are solutions using JavaScript and jQuery. Here's one that I wrote and use a lot:

[jQuery .centerInClient() plugin](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/459873.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `position: absolute` is exactly that you want to specify how far from the margins of the page your div should be placed. Since you do not know the width of the screen a priori, there is no way to center it.

I guess you just want to remove the div from the page flow, while keeping it centered. In this case it may be enough to add a container div, like

```
<div id="external">
    <div id="internal">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#external {
    position: absolute
}

#internal {
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

I did not test the above layout, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method using percentages:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Simply set your desired page width, and set the left margin as half of the remainder. In this case, the `width` is 80%, leaving 20%. Set `left:`to 10% and it will center the div on the page.

Using this method will allow the div to scale with different window sizes and screen resolutions as well.