# CSS absolute position won't work with margin-left:auto margin-right: auto

Tags: html, css, position

Say you have the following CSS applied to a div tag

```css
.divtagABS {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

the `margin-left` and `margin-right` does not take effect

but if you have relative, it works fine
i.e.

```css
.divtagREL {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Why is that? I just want to center an element.

Can someone explain why setting margins to auto in absolute position does not work?

Comment: just use `margin: auto;`. with absolute position, all other style elements(regarding position/etc) are ignored.

Comment: Wrap it in a <center> tag and set the width of .divtagABS to 100%.

Comment: I can confirm: even though some say that this statement is outdated, I noticed a not-centering failure for `position: absolute;` on IE Edge.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**EDIT : this answer used to claim that it isn't possible to center an absolutely positioned element with `margin: auto;`, but this simply isn't true. Because this is the most up-voted and accepted answer, I guessed I'd just change it to be correct.**

When you apply the following CSS to an element

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

And then give the element a fixed width and height, such as 200px or 40%, the element **will** center itself.

Here's [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38tjjdpd/16/) that demonstrates the effect.

Comment: url: http://www.vision.to/articles/margins-and-absolute-positioning.php is not working, please replace

Comment: courtesy of wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20130117135705/http://www.vision.to/articles/margins-and-absolute-positioning.php

Comment: "An element with position absolute cannot be centered..." Actually, this is _not_ true: The key is to set all `top/bottom/left/right` properties to `0` and declare `width` and `height`, then `margin: auto` will automatically center the absolutely positioned element. See: [Absolute Centering technique](http://codepen.io/shshaw/details/gEiDt); it's also on [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/).

Comment: And in order to make a width pseudo-dynamic, use `width: 100%;` and (i.e.) `max-width: 500px;`.

Comment: Yep you need to add `width: 100%` to make it work with edge and IE9-11.

Comment: I think you only need to set left, right and a (max)width for it to center, No need for bottom or top for horizontal alignment. Although for best practice you should set at least one of those so browsers cant misinterpret

Comment: I managed to center my element thanks to this answer BUT setting `top` AND `bottom` poses a problem for me. It makes the element not the right height (content overflows). Better to set only one of them. Actually just `left` and `right` are needed for the horizontal centering with `margin: X auto`.

Comment: And you can use `inset: 0` instead of setting all 4 values (top - right - bottom - left) to 0. Not available for IE, unfortunately.

Answer (score 71):

I've [used this trick to center an absolutely positioned element](http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/). Though, you have to know the element's `width`.

```css
.divtagABS {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }
```

Basically, you use `left: 50%`, then back it out half of it's `width` with a negative `margin`.

Comment: Yep, this is what you should use if the element has a fixed width.

Comment: You can use margin-left:-25%; to center it instead of hard-coding a number.

Comment: @AaronHarun - sadly, no that won't work the way you expect. I think the 25% will be based on the parent's width. I set up a code pen to test it out: http://codepen.io/chippper/pen/xwKIl  - you can toggle the last line of CSS to see what I mean.

Comment: This triggered me into [a similar trick](https://github.com/cauerego/cregox-scripts/commit/f75fcbb9f1fa9beaad351095f5814af0ce811591) but using `margin-left: -50%;`. Oddly enough, it fixed a very weird alignment issue for me!

Comment: @chipcullen @AaronHarun You can use `transform: translateX(-25%)` which uses it's own width. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35723851/2054731 (As you noted, @chipcullen, `width: -25%` will use the parent element's width, typically not what you want.)

Comment: @ArneHugo - I think that is what the previous comment was alluding to. At the time I wrote this answer, transform wasn't well supported - thankfully that has changed! :)

Comment: This works fine with max-width too. So it's flexible enough.

Answer (score 40):

if the absolute element has a width,you can use the code below

```css
.divtagABS{
    width:300px;
    positon:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! But why isn't it working unless left and right are set ?

Comment: Very nice solution. Works also with width:100% under Bootstrap ;)

Comment: If you want to make it centre vertically and horizontally then just expand this to top: 0; bottom: 0; combine this with a CSS 3 transition for width and height and you have a pretty nice effect

Comment: I think this is the horizontal case of the [Absolute Centering technique](http://codepen.io/shshaw/details/gEiDt) (also: [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)), which uses `margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` (with declared `width` and `height`) for both horizontal and vertical centering. The linked articles explain how this method works and compares it to other centering methods.

Comment: @geoffroy because `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` are setted to `auto` by default and this, together with an absolute layout, actually prevent `margin: auto` to be noticeable

Answer (score 25):

**Working JSFiddle below.**
When using position absolute, `margin: 0 auto` will not work, but you can do like this (will also scale):

```css
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

*Update:* Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b7p6bd8/)

Comment: Best work with Absolute position div's but have some issue in IE10 when positioning div has width more than parent width... :(

Answer (score 2):

All answers were just a suggested solutions or workarounds. But still don't get answer to the question: **why margin:auto works with position:relative but does not with position:absolute.**

Following explanation was helpful for me:

"Margins make little sense on absolutely positioned elements since such elements are removed from the normal flow, thus **they cannot push away any other elements on the page**. Using margins like this can only affect the placement of the element to which the margin is applied, not any other element."
http://www.justskins.com/forums/css-margins-and-absolute-82168.html

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be confusing until you realize some nuances of different positionings.

Margins work similarly for relative and absolute elements, but margins are relative to a 'bounding box.' You have to consider what is the bounding box of the element, to apply margins against.

- For a relative positioned element, the bounding box is its parent element.
- For an absolute positioned element, the bounding box is itself.
- For a relative positioned element, left/right/top/bottom rules position the element itself.
- For an absolute positioned element, left/right/top/bottom rules position the element's bounding box.

This is why to center a relative positioned element, you only have to set margins and it works.

To center an absolute positioned element, you have to set the margins, and also set the bounding box (left/right/top/bottom).

Answer (score 1):

I already had this same issue and I've got the solution writing a container (.divtagABS-container, in your case) absolutely positioned and then relatively positioning the content inside it (.divtagABS, in your case).

Done! The margin-left and margin-right AUTO for your .divtagABS will now work.

Answer (score -1):

If the element is position absolutely, then it isn't relative, or in reference to any object - including the page itself.  So `margin: auto;` can't decide where the middle is.

Its waiting to be told explicitly, using `left` and `top` where to position itself.

You can still center it programatically, using javascript or somesuch.

Answer (score -5):

When you are defining styles for division which is positioned `absolute`ly, they specifying margins are useless. Because they are no longer inside the regular DOM tree.

You can use float to do the trick.

```
.divtagABS {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```