# styling floating table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the JavaScript/jQuery script available [here](http://code.google.com/p/js-floating-table-headers/) to have the table headers floating while scrolling down/up. My table is center aligned. When I scroll down, the headers float but they get left aligned, rest of the table is center aligned though. Here is the snapshot of the output that I am getting right now:

[image: Here is the snapshot of the output that I am getting right now:]

What exactly do I need to edit in this JavaScript/jQuery code or my PHP/HTML code to have them center aligned?

#### Update

[Example of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/VHaaw/)

Comment: Could you give an example on jsFiddle to help?

Comment: [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHaaw/) that I attempted to create. The headers are not floating for some reason though.

Comment: Oh, it is better to use jQuery plugin. This one —http://fixedheadertable.com/, for example.

Comment: That plugin is quite impressive! I am trying to have it in my webpage, I added the following code to my code:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.fixedheadertable.js"></script>

The tagging is done properly, however, its not working as expected, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elegant of scripts you've found, so I think yaponyal's advice is sound.

There were a few reasons why your fiddle didn't work: jsfiddle doesn't like the script's direct onload event attachment, so you can change it to:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    this.build_header();
});
```

Additionally, the setheader function that runs every time you scroll, has to also set a horizontal position for the header.

```
this.header.style.left = this.table_obj.offsetLeft + "px";
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998260/css-absolute-position-wont-work-with-margin-leftauto-margin-right-auto) for the reason why it can't be automatically centered. You could instead modify the script to put the cloned table header in a div with centered text alignment if you wanted to.

Also, the script sets a top value for the header without appending "px". That didn't work in my browser, I had to change it into:

```
this.header.style.top=Math.round(screenpos) + "px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VHaaw/3/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to use the plugin that yaponyal suggested, but have difficulty in using it. 
I added the following code to my code: <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/…; <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.fixedheadertable.js"></script> 
The tagging is done properly, however, its not working as expected, what am I missing?

Comment: @rad: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VHaaw/5/ I had to put the table in a div with the size I wanted. Not sure if that's the author's intention or what though.

Comment: I am going with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/VHaaw/6/
As a next step, I want to add the header at the bottom too! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On page load, does the header appear right at the top? If so, I would suggest detaching the header into a separate div, styling it according to your needs and then setting a position fixed to the div. You can use the css property margin: 0 auto; to center data according to the width of the page.

Comment: The table header is not at the top of my webpage.