# Can't center this absolute element

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I'm currently changing a PSD design to a HTML site. I've come into an issue however. I am unable to center a certain element. I've tried all the usual tricks.

http://lowhop.net/

See here the main blue header is out of line (not centered). I tried

`#slider{
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;`

Before, however it didn't work reliably. (Appeared only to work on my screen resolution/browser).

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be positioned absolutely? Does it even need to be centered? It looks like you've positioned `div#navBar` simply by adding `margin-left: 85px`. It seems that you could use that same method for `div#slider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly set the width of the slider DIV, you can use another trick to center it:

```
#slider 
{
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(../img/sliderbg_09_09.png);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 982px;
  height: 251px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -491px; /** half DIV width */
}
```

I'd probably steer away from having this as a position absolute DIV, doesn't look like it needs it but that's a quick and dirty centering :)

Hope that helps

Comment: Ach - @ottis, I was writing my answer at the same time. OP: basically, this.

Comment: great minds think alike @chipcullen :) no problem UnleashedPixel

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly define a `width` on the element when using `margin: 0 auto` to center.

Block elements take up the full available viewport width unless you explicitly give them a width.

Comment: `#slider {
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 2;
 background-image: url(../img/sliderbg_09_09.png);
 width: 982px;
 height: 251px;
}` Causes the effect below

Comment: Position absolute was removed. Now this has occured http://pasteboard.co/C3Fl2K1.png

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use absolute positioning, you can use [something like my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998260/css-absolute-position-wont-work-with-margin-leftauto-margin-right-auto/9998332#9998332).

Basically, you declare an explicit width for your element, then give it

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -[your width/2];
```

Answer (score 0):

like user showdev mentioned :

> Does it need to be positioned absolutely? Does it even need to be centered? It looks like you've positioned div#navBar simply by adding margin-left: 85px. It seems that you could use that same method for div#slider.

you have

```
#navBar {
  background-image: url("../img/navbg_07.png");
  display: block;
  height: 38px;
  margin-left: 85px; /* attention on this */
  margin-top: 31px;
  position: relative;
  width: 879px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and this

```
#slider {
  background-image: url("../img/sliderbg_09_09.png");
  display: block;
  height: 251px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 982px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

so, try 'margin-left: 85px;' your #slider.