# cannot center table in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I have these two tables

```
    <table  id="pointsTable" >
          <th> One </th>                                           
          <th> Two </th>                               
          <th> Three </th>
          <tr>
           <td  id="one" ></td>               
           <td  id="two"></td>              
           <td  id="three"></td>                            
          </tr>
    </table>                                                                            
            
   <table id="pointsTableSmall" style="text-align: center;">
          <tr>
             <th> One </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td  id="one"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Two </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td  id="two" ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Three</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td  id="three" ></td>
          </tr>
   </table>
```

The first is visible in large screens and the second one, the smaller, is visible in smaller screens.

Their css is

```
#pointsTable, #pointsTableSmall{
    border: 0;
    border-style: 0;   
    margin: auto !important;
    padding: auto;
    text-align: center !important;    
        
}
```

Their wrap div has

```
#pointWrap{
    text-align: center;
}
```

In Firefox 45.0.1 the table is aligned left , has margin : auto and no padding                                                                                                                            . There is a gap in the right side between the left aligned-gap an its container `div`.

I cannot center that `pointsTableSmall` table. How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Update**

Now, the table is

```
            <div class="container center-block" id="pointsTableSmallWrap">
                <table id="pointsTableSmall" align="center" class="center-block">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Hey </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="heyT", id="heyTS"> more hey</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Hi</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="hiA" id="hiAS" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Yo</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="yoU" id="yoUS" ></td>
                    </tr>
               </table> 
           </div>
```

Each `<td>` has graphics from the [progressbar.js](http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) library.

The css is

```
#pointsTableSmall{
    display: none;
    text-align: center !important;      
    align-self: center; 
    alignment-adjust: central; 
    align-content: center;
    align : center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

#pointsTableSmallWrap{
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align :center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#pointsTableSmall > tbody, #pointsTableSmall > tbody > tr{
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align :center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

*The problem*

In Firefox the table always sits on the left (check image to help you). I dont know how to center it. I tried

> I replaced table with bootstrap `div class="col-md-4"` but they go one under the other even in medium screen sizes and look ugly
>
> I replaced table with flexbox that is awesome in small screens , but again in medium screens they dont stick one net to the other and look ugly
>
> I tried adding `margin-left`, `margin-right` on the tables and the wrap , but nothing.

Please help me center this table

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the question / problem. You want to center both tables?
https://jsfiddle.net/m8pyhenx/2/

Comment: what about adding clear:both; to css?

Comment: Please share your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't like asking for attention or reputation, but it might be a good idea to mark one of the answers as accepted

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few things wrong in your code.

You've put a comma between `class="heyT"` and `id="heyTS"` in your HTML, as well as some unneeded whitespace

In your CSS, you've used `alignment-adjust`, which isn't supported by any browser (I think?). Googling the property didn't make the W3C or Mozilla spec show up. You've also used `align-self` and `align-content`, which are flex-box properties. You are not using flex-box in your code. You're also using `align`, which doesn't have a meaning.

Then there's the place where you apply `margin: 0 auto;`, but after that you apply `margin-left: 1%;` and `margin-right: 1%;`. Having these rules together means you end up with a margin of `0 1% 0 1%` (0 at the top and bottom. 1% at the left and right).

### The solution to your problem

In [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm6mof2b/), you can see that the table has a width of 50% and that it's aligned to the center. You can remove the width of 50%, and have it be as small as possible.

All I've done is remove the container `div`, as it didn't serve any purpose. I also removed the styles that you were applying to `#pointsTableSmall > tbody, #pointsTableSmall > tbody > tr` also because it didn't serve any purpose.

Basically, the thing stopping you from having it centered, was because the table had a width of 100%. The only thing necessary to center a table is `margin: 0 auto;` and a width that **isn't** 100%

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow:auto;
```

Quite often, I find that I've missed a bit of CSS which is critical in allowing `Margin: 0 auto;` to work. It must have a width. It mustn't be floating left, right or centred. It must be displayed block. You mustn't give the div a fixed position.

Refer here: [What, exactly, is needed for "margin: 0 auto;" to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)

Comment: You can use margin: auto; on an element that is positioned absolutely or fixed. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19341954/3791358)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're overriding your own declarations of margin, with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
```

The code becomes:

```
margin: 0 1%;
```

For hidding the table in media queries, changing `display` property between *block* and *none* is enough.

a) To **center the table**:

```
#pointsTableSmall {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

b) To **center *td* elements**:

```
<td align="center" id="heyTS"> more hey</td>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNEgxz

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention that the css of the `#pointsTableSmall` has `display: none;` and then I wrote some media-queries to make it visible in small screens.

So in my media queries I do

```
  #pointsTableSmall {
    display: block;
  }
```

All I had to do is replace the css of `#pointsTableSmall` with the one Gust van de Wal wrote [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hm6mof2b/).

Completely remove the css about `#pointsTableSmallWrap` and `#pointsTableSmall > tbody, #pointsTableSmall > tbody > tr` and remove the `pointsTableSmallWrap` `div` itself.

Also, and here is the trick, replace

```
  #pointsTableSmall {
    display: block;
  }
```

with

```
  #pointsTableSmall {
    display: inline;
  }
```

`display: inline` is the default value.

This was the trick. This. Was. The Trick. Just a simple value. Oh, I love CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to encapsulate the table in a div and give the center alignment to this div with display: inline-block; and margin: auto;.
You will probbaly need to give a width=100% to your table

Answer (score 1):

the question is not clear but i think you want to make table center instead of text align center so,

May be your table has `float` property in other css that's why your element is not centering `margin:auto;` will not work with `floted` element if you want to center you have to remove float property.

**Another Solution** take another element before table and use table inside it for example

Html

```
<div class="center">
   // your table here
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
   width:500px; /* waht ever width */
   margin:auto;
}
```

**Note**: in your code you are using `Margin` property in **tr**, The margin property don't work with `display:table` `display:table:cell;` `display : table-row` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make the inner table in center , no matter what you do when you resize , just add this

1. `margin-left:auto`
2. `margin-right:auto`

into the id of the specific table you want in the css...